# Why is my counter not working? (Verilog)

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I'm trying to create a counter that will display how many 1's are in the inputs. This is a little piece of code in the program:

```
input [3:0] X;
integer count = 0;
reg [3:0] i;
initial 
begin
   for (i=0; i<4l i=i+1)
      if(X[i] == 1'b1) begin
         count = count+1;
      end

end
```

The problem is that whenever I simulate this program, and force any values on the input X (i.e 1111)
The counter never adds anything, stays at 0 through all iterations.

Any help would be appreciated.

Updated design:

The whole code consists of writing a parity checker. It has 4 inputs and 1 input Even_Odd. If Even_Odd = 1, checks for even parity (Outputs Y=1 if true) if it's odd it checks for odd (Outputs Y=1 if true)

```
module Parity(Y, X, Even_Odd);

input [3:0] X;
input Even_Odd;
output Y;
reg Y;
integer count=0; //initializing counter = 0
reg [3:0] i;

initial
begin
  for(i=0; i<4; i = i+1) begin //iterates through input bits
    $display("Current loop %d", i);
    if (X[i] == 1'b1) begin
    count = count + 1;
  end
  $display("Count = %d", count);
end


if (Even_Odd == 1'b1)
  if (count % 2 == 0) //checking if count is even or odd
    Y = 1'b1;
  else
    Y = 1'b0;
 
  if (count % 2 == 0)
    Y = 1'b1;
  else
    Y = 1'b0;
end

endmodule
```

Comment: `for` loops in Verilog don't cause things to happen one after the other. They cause multiple logic elements to be instantiated.

Comment: Since there are only 16 cases it seems like a case statement would be a nice straightforward way to do it. No doubt the compiler (synthesis tool) is adept at optimizing case statements. Try to remember that verilog looks like a programming language, but it was conceived as a hardware description language. Some concepts from programming do not apply. In particular, there is no flow of control or sequencing from one statement to the next.

Comment: With just 4 bits I would add the individual bits. `counter <= X[0] + X[1] + X[2] + X[3];` No need for a loop.

Comment: XOR gate is an odd parity checker.

Comment: @Syed It would be more appropriate to say that the **binary XOR operation** is an odd parity checker. The behavior of an XOR **gate** with more than two inputs is debatable.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson : 2-input and 3-input tables for XOR operation [show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPull.png) that an XOR gate is an odd parity detector.

Comment: @Syed The image you linked is not a 3-input gate, it is the binary XOR operation applied twice: a XOR b XOR c. Furthermore, the image is not an authoritative source.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, perhaps you can load the truth table of a 3-input XOR gate from an authoritative source?

Comment: @Syed That's exactly the problem. To the best of my knowledge there is no authoritative definition of the behavior of an XOR gate with more than 2 inputs. Some say it is odd parity but other say it is truly an exclusive OR (one and only one input is 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count` remains at 0 because your code executes at time 0 in the `initial` block.  The value of the `X` module input is indeterminate even if you set it to `1111` at time 0 outside of the module.

To observe this, you can also display `X` in your `$display` statements.  I created a trivial testbench to demonstrate.  I modified the `Parity` module, removing all code that does not affect the value of `count`, and adjusted the indentation to be clearer.  It is also helpful to display the simulation time when debugging.

```
module Parity (X);
    input [3:0] X;
    integer     count=0;
    reg [3:0]   i;

    initial begin
        for (i=0; i<4; i=i+1) begin
            $display($time, " Current loop i=%0d X=%b", i, X[i]);
            if (X[i] == 1'b1) begin
                count = count + 1;
            end
            $display($time, " Count = %0d", count);
        end
    end
endmodule

module tb;
    reg [3:0] X = 4'b1111;
    Parity i0 (X);
endmodule
```

This prints:

```
               0 Current loop i=0 X=x
               0 Count = 0
               0 Current loop i=1 X=x
               0 Count = 0
               0 Current loop i=2 X=x
               0 Count = 0
               0 Current loop i=3 X=x
               0 Count = 0
```

As you can see, the value of `X` is `x` (unknown) instead of `1`.  This means that `if (X[i] == 1'b1)` evaluates to false.  The time (0) is shown in the 1st column.

One way to fix this is to add delay inside the `initial` block:

```
    initial begin
        #1;
        for (i=0; i<4; i=i+1) begin
```

This prints:

```
               1 Current loop i=0 X=1
               1 Count = 1
               1 Current loop i=1 X=1
               1 Count = 2
               1 Current loop i=2 X=1
               1 Count = 3
               1 Current loop i=3 X=1
               1 Count = 4
```

Now, the counter is counting.

---

You can run this on different simulators on [edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/AiAZ).  When I run with Synopsys VCS (without the `#1` delay), it actually counts at time 0, thereby demonstrating the non-determinism.

---

Keep in mind that the `initial` block only executes once during simulation.  You likely want to do the count every time `X` changes.  In that case, you would use an `always` block with appropriate sensitivity list.